# Calling Elasticsearch Rest API from Ruby script

Tags: ruby, rest, elasticsearch, rest-client

Im new to Elasticsearch and Ruby script, Please help me in resolving this. I want add/remove aliases from index everyday by cron job.

I tried using shell script as below and its working as expected

```
curl -XPOST "http://$es_host:9200/_aliases" -d "$json"
```

Ruby Script

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'rest_client'

target="http://localhost:9200/_aliases"

request = RestClient::Request.new(
        :method => :post,
        :url => target,
        :payload => input)
puts request.execute
```

input is valid json(i tested it). but Ruby script throwing below error.

```
> ruby-1.9.3-p374@11.4.0-1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!': 400 Bad Request (RestClient::BadRequest)     from
> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@11.4.0-1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:230:in `process_result'  from
> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@11.4.0-1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:178:in `block in transmit'   from
> /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in
> `start'   from
> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@11.4.0-1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'    from
> /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@11.4.0-1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in
> `execute'     from es_alias.rb:56:in `<main>'
```

P.S - Ruby script printing all aliases if I just remove payload and try.

Comment: Where is `input` defined?

Comment: its valid json, did not include it due to security reasons.

Comment: Try [turning on logging in RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#logging) and post the results here.

Comment: is the way i am making post call with parameter is correct? because in shell script i am passing -d then json but json goes into payload in ruby.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8189932/how-do-i-make-rubys-restclient-gem-respect-content-type-on-post) -- it could be your problem. You probably need to set the content-type.

Comment: I got this error now after setting content type to application/json. RestClient.post "http://localhost:9200/_aliases", 3000 byte(s) length, "Accept"=>"*/*; q=0.5, application/xml", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "Content-Length"=>"3000"
# => 500 InternalServerError | application/json 120 bytes

Comment: payload should be string instead of json, data=input.to_json.to_json
request = RestClient::Request.new(
        :method => :post,
        :url => target,
        :payload => data)
puts request.execute
now getting request timed out, so going to increase timeout and check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just started using elasticsearch ruby client and its solved the purpose and its better to use elasticsearch ruby client to do operations in elasticsearch because ruby client provides connection pooling (connecting through multiple elasticsearch nodes)

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/Elasticsearch